# Primality testing though trial division.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am having difficulty to understand this statement mentioned [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/comp-number-theory/a/trial-division):

> Remember that any composite integer n is build out of two or more primes n = P * P …
>
> P is largest when n has exactly two divisors which are equal to each other.

It makes sense for examples like 49 (7*7), 25 (5*5), what about 12, it should be less than 4 and yes it comes out 3 so, it works but why?

Comment: $12$ is between $9$ and $16$ and thus $\sqrt{12}$ is some real number between $3$ and $4$.  Let's assume we have the number $x^2 = 12$...any _other_ divisors (possibly integer) would be got by doing $\alpha x\frac{x}{\alpha}$--assume $\alpha > 1$.  Therefore there is a number _smaller_ than the square root _and_ a corresponding number _greater_ than the square root that _must_ be divisible by the original number (if such a number exists).

Comment: It's a shame that a text as helpless as the lines quoted above can sail under the heading "academic".

Comment: @ChristianBlatter sorry, but I didn't get you.

Comment: I looked at the quoted source, and the logo of a "Khan Academy" came into view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a positive integer $n$ is prime you need to see if there is an integer that divides it other than $1$ and $n$.

So a way to do it is to check for every number in $\{1,2,\dots n-1\}$ and see if it divides $n$ or not.

However, there is an easier way to check. If $n$ is a composite number then it has a divisor other than $1$ and itself, so we can write $n=ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers different from $1$ and $n$.

notice that either $a\leq \sqrt{n}$ or $b\leq \sqrt{n}$. Because otherwise we have $n=ab>\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}=n$.

So we conclude if $n$ is composite it has a divisor between $2$ and $\sqrt{n}$.

So now, if we want to check if a number is prime or not, we don't have to try for all the integers in $\{2,3,4\dots n\}$, we just have to try with the positive integers that are smaller or equal to $\sqrt{n}$. And these are much less.

Comment: In your proof you have assumed that the $$a \le sqrt(n)$$, while that was my question. Other thing is why not n = abc? for example: 30=2*3*5.

Comment: lol, I didn't assume $a\leq \sqrt{n}$

Comment: Can you please explain why you considered only two factors of n? why not 3 or more?

Comment: I just wrote n as the productos of two divisors.

Answer (score 0):

What your article is trying to show is that a positive integer $n$ is prime if and only if $n$ is not divisible by any prime $p$ with $1<p\le\sqrt{n}$; and if such a $p$ can be found then $n$ is composite. This then implies that instead of trial division by every number $d$ in $2\le d\le n-1$, we need only check for $d$ in $2\le d\le\sqrt{n}$.

So let $n\ge4$ be a composite number.  Now let  $a$ and $b$ be positive divisors of $n$ which are different from $1$ and $n$: if $a$ divides $n$ $b$ times then $n=a\cdot b$. Note that we can always write $n$ as a product of two positive factors, $a$ and $b$, say, and these can be composite or prime, it doesn't matter for what comes next.

Now either $a\leq \sqrt{n}$ or $b\leq \sqrt{n}$. All this means is that if $n$ is a perfect square, then great, we have $a=b=\sqrt{n}$; otherwise one of the factors has to be smaller than $\sqrt{n}$, and the other factor has to be greater than $\sqrt{n}$.

**Remark:** We need not consider $n$ as a product of three factors, $n=abc$,  as here we would just let $bc=d$ and write $n=ad$, then continue as above.

Consider these examples where the factors $a$ and $b$ can be prime or composite:

(i) Let $a=3$, $b=4$, $n=12$. Then
$$ 3<\sqrt{12}\approx 3.464<4$$ 
or, say $a=2$, $b=6$, $n=12$. Then
$$ 2<\sqrt{12}\approx 3.464<6$$
Illustrating the fact that $12$ is composite as both of its distinct prime factors $2<\sqrt{12}$, or $3<\sqrt{12}$.

(ii) Let $a=3$, $b=7$, $n=21$. Then
$$ 3<\sqrt{21}\approx 4.583<7$$ 
so $21$ is composite as we have exhibited a prime factor $3<\sqrt{21}$. Note $\sqrt{21}<7$, so we do get prime factors $>\sqrt{n}$ occurring, but for composite numbers there must always be some prime factor $<\sqrt{n}$.

(iii) Finally consider if $n$ is a perfect square, say $a=b=5$, $n=25$. Then
$$5=\sqrt{25}$$

Some remarks on the article you cite:

(1) Remember that any composite integer n is build out of two or more primes n = P * P …

This should be more general, they have written P * P.., using the same P twice no exponent. It should say something like: If $n$ is composite then it is not $1$ or a single prime, but has a unique prime factorisation: 
$$n=p_{1}^{a_1}\cdot p_{2}^{a_2}\cdot p_{3}^{a_3}\dotsm p_{k}^{a_k}=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_{i}^{a_i}$$
where the $a_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge1}$.

The next statement:

(2) P is largest when n has exactly two divisors which are equal to each other.

This is very confusing as it is not immediately clear what 'largest' in this context is meant to convey. They look at the specific case when $n$ is a square of a prime $n=p\cdot p=p^2$, and so the divisors of $n$ are $\{1,p,n\}$, and because $n$ is square they are saying the divisor $p$ divides $n$ 'twice'. Why $p$ is 'largest' in their eyes is (maybe) because $p=\sqrt{n}$ in this case, and is not just $<\sqrt{n}$. But as we saw with $21=3\cdot 7$, you do get the case where $p>\sqrt{n}$, but this came with the proviso that some other prime $q<\sqrt{n}$, plus $7$ is larger than $3$, so don't get this all mixed up.